# Automate Mail Merge

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, ms-word

Here is the problem from my original post:

---

I have a Word template (dotm) that has fields i would like filled in from a one-line/entry Excel file.  I have a "Rough.txt", the contents of which i would like to insert into a specific place in this same mail-merge-generated document in addition to the information from the Excel file.

i would like to generate a DOC or DOCX from this scripting process that is saved in the same directory as the above-mentioned files.  I would like this to be done by clicking run on a bat file or similar type of situation that does not involve me manually opening the file and clicking the buttons every time i want to do it.  I would like it to be simpler than opening word manually and running the macro.

Plus, if i can put it in an executable/"runnable" file like a bat or something similar, then i can attach a shortcut to it and run it with Cortana voice commands.  This is why i am going about it from this angle.  This would be a GEM to have.  Important here is that it runs when i tell it to, not scheduled at a certain time.  I have done this with other bats with great success.

---

So i used a combination of what all the answers were to construct the following:

I have a bat file with a bunch of FART commands in it to correct many common grammar errors in a document; it's irrelevant and long, so i won't post it here.  It's called FINISH-1.bat.

Then i have a second BAT file, FINISH-2.bat, which contains only the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe" "/mRunAllMacros" "C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\NewKCJob\Transcript.docx"
```

So then I created about 20 find/replace Microsoft Word macros for styles which i will not post here since this was not relevant to the question.

I made two more macros in Word which are relevant to my issue.  The following completes the mail merge for my Excel file, which is exported from Jotform.

```
Sub MailMergeCover()
'
' MailMergeCover Macro
'
'
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
    "C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\JotformExport.xlsx", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
    WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\JotformExport.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet " _
    , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Submissions$`", SQLStatement1:="", _
    SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With
Windows("Transcript.docx [Compatibility Mode]").Activate
End Sub
```

And the following macro inserts my "Rough.Txt" document into the same transcript/Word document at the bookmark i inserted called "rough":

```
Sub InsertRough()
'
' InsertRough Macro
'
'
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("rough") = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("rough").Select
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\NewKCJob\Rough.txt"
Else
    MsgBox "Bookmark ""rough"" does not exist!"
End If
End Sub
```

The next step was to tie them all together in Word in a certain order so that my find/replace macros i mentioned earlier also apply to "Rough.txt":

```
Sub RunAllMacros()
Call InsertRough
Call Macro1
Call Macro2
Call Macro3
Call Macro4
Call Macro5
Call Macro6
Call Macro7
Call Macro8
Call Macro9
Call Macro10
Call Macro11
Call Macro12
Call Macro13
Call Macro14
Call Macro15
Call Macro16
Call Macro17
Call Macro18
Call Macro19
Call Macro20
Call MailMergeCover
End Sub
```

The second-to-last step was to make a third bat file, FINISH.bat, which Cortana will be using, to call the two bat files:

```
call "C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\NewKCJob\FINISH-1.bat"
call "C:\Transcription\Transcription\In Progress\NewKCJob\FINISH-2.bat"
```

The last step was to create a shortcut to FINISH.bat in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs called "Finish Job" for Cortana to index.

Now, i can say, "Hey, Cortana, open finish job," and it will do this for me all automatically.

i have just shaved 20 minutes to an hour off EVERY transcript i complete as i was doing many of these corrections manually.  i would like to respect and follow the rules as much as i can, so if i am not giving enough detail or doing something abnormally, let me know so i can fix it.  Again, thank you so much!!  Really, i could not have crafted this without your help.

Comment: What's a "mail merge?"

Comment: Some questions...where is the process started from now?  The excel file?  does the data in your .txt file change or is it always the same?  does the data in your excel file change?  Is the layout in your word template the same for each file?  I'm thinking you can do this entirely from excel.

Comment: Thank you.  at Somethingdark: to go with the Google definition, a mail merge is "the automatic addition of names and addresses from a database to letters and envelopes in order to facilitate sending mail, especially advertising, to many addresses." | at cplett: 1) Well, right now i am just doing a regular mail merge and/or filling in the blanks manually, so the process is manual and starts in Word.  2)The data is one line's worth with a header in Excel.  3) The content of Rough.txt will be different every time i run it, but the name will remain the same each time.  4) Yes.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: `winword /mmacroname` runs a macro. _Alt + T, M, R_ turns on/off recording a macro.

Comment: Why not just put the contents of your .txt file into your Excel file, and add it to the document as any other data from Excel? That would simplify things in my opinion.

Comment: For automation, I would use .vbs files. They can do a lot more than batch files. If cortana can't run a .vbs, you can create a one-line batch file to launch your .vbs.

Comment: One more thing: did you try any of the above codes? What is wrong with them? Do you understand them? Or are these just some copy-pasted codes from all around the internet that you don't really understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provide:

1. Create a template (*.dotm) for this. Double-clicking it in the Windows
   Explorer/the Desktop will create a new document.
2. The text file: I'm assuming insert "as is" with no subsequent
       processing, so just use the Insert/Text/Object/Text from file
       command in the Word UI. Click the arrow next to the "Insert" button
       in the dialog box and choose to insert with  Link.
3. Use Word's built-in Mailings/Mail Merge tool to link to the Excel
   data-source
4. Record a macro to execute the mail merge.
5. Create a macro named AutoNew in the template and copy the content of
   the recorded macro into it. This macro will execute automatically
   when a new document is created from the template.